# Division of Python Complex Numbers

Tags: python-3.x, division, complex-numbers, complex-data-types

I am trying to divide two complex numbers and not getting the desired result. How does division work for Python Complex numbers ?

Input values are: (2+3j) and (2+3j)

I have tried the below logic and this does not seem to work.

numerator_real = (real * conjugate.real) - (imag * conjugate.imag); // real

numerator_imag = (real * conjugate.imag) + (imag * conjugate.real); // imag

denom = x.real * x.real  + x.imag * x.imag;

```
complex(numerator_real/denom, numerator_imag/denom)
```

**Expected/Desired Result is:** `1+0j`

**My output is** `1.3+0j`

Comment: You have your output but you missed the input values.

Comment: Python is dynamically typed; variables are not explicitly typed when they are initialized except in the value they are set to. The `double` keyword before lines 1, 2, & 3 is not standard Python.

Comment: @KlausD.: Sorry missed adding the input values earlier. Updated the description to reflect the input values.

Comment: What's your code to divide these numbers? Just doing `(2+3j)/(2+3j)` produces your desired result for me.

Comment: Hi @HS-nebula : I am not clear with the logic of how to get output as 1+0j. Can you help let me know the logic to get the division output ?

Comment: Open Python and type `(2+3j)/(2+3j)` and it will produce `1+0j`. It also works if you save them as variables.